# how can I assign parameter variable in into asp:DropDown under CssClass?

Tags: c#, .net

Does any one how can I assign how can I parameter variable in into asp:DropDown under CssClass?

Example:

I have the following code

```
  <tr>   
        <th class="graytext r">Test:</th>
        <td>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="sTest" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTest" 
            DataValueField="TestID" CssClass="Test2ID" DataTextField="TestName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>  
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test %>"
            SelectCommand="app_Test" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I want it to assign both TestID and Test2ID into the DataValueField. So, let said if the output for TestID is 100 and Test2ID is 200 then the result will be CssClas="200"

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this right, set it through server side

```
<%=Test2ID%>
```

Comment: that will now work. `Test2ID` is a data bound field not a variable.

Comment: @for cssClass i don't think so , it might be static.